# Laravel Collective Syntax

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm learning laravel (5.5) from a book.
I installed laravel collective, the book says, to link a css file write like this:
`{{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}}` It works fine.
but in the output two empty `{}` braces appear (because they are not being used as part of the syntax). So, I removed them and it still works fine.
Question is which syntax is correct?
this `{{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}}`
or `{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}`
???

Comment: either this {!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!} or {{ HTML::style('css/app.css') }}
not this {{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}}

Comment: As I mentioned in the question that your suggestion works. But are you saying that it was wrong in the book? Should I expect other blunders like these. (because I also had another issue where ignoring the writer solved the problem)

Comment: As per your question you said your output is empty and {} bracket appear . As much I know  above mentioned syntax work fine but last syntax wouldn't work

Comment: Sorry! I guess I failed to explain. I meant to say that with ```{{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}}``` syntax the css file gets attached but two empty braces appear in output.

Comment: Could you please add snippet of your output

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Laravel tries to help you with security within your apps. When outputting data using the `{{ $foo }}` data, Laravel automatically calls the `htmlspecialchars()` method to prevent XSS attacks. In some cases you do want or need to output HTML, that's why Laravel created a separated syntax for that: `{!! $foo !!}`.

So to answer your question: `{!! $foo !!}` is the correct syntax.

Off topic:

If you'd like to not use the unescaped data syntax, you could write you're CSS linking like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```